# Stationarity of an Integral Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $f$ be a continous deterministic function defined on $\left[0,c\right]$ and $(B_{t}^{H})_{t\geq 0}$ be a fBM with $H\in \left(0,1\right)$. We define a Process $\left(X_{t}\right)_{t\geq 0}$ with
$$X_{t} = \int_{0}^{c} f(s) B^{H}_{t+s}ds.$$
Am I right assuming that $\left(X_{t}\right)$ is centered, gaussian and stationary?

Comment: Where do you see a problem? Can't one approximate the integral be Riemann sums to verify the desired properties?

Comment: How could $(X_t)$ be stationary when $(B^H_t)$ obviously isn't?